# Is there any way that I can control the CPU resources sharing among Xen virtual machines?

Tags: linux, virtualization, xen, cpu-usage, vcpu

I'm going to set up three or two Xen virtual machines on one physical machine. I want those VMs to share different CPU time on average. I've Googled for a long while but still haven't been able to find a way to achieve my goal. I'm wondering is that possible? And how? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both CPU pining:

http://panoskrt.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/pin-cpu-cores-to-specific-xen-domu-guest/

And the CreditScheduler:

http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/CreditScheduler

The CPU pining will assign real CPUs to specific virtual machines while the CreditScheduler allows you to limit CPU usage by the virtual machines.

Comment: You can set the number of "pinned" CPUs higher than the VCPUs - then a subset of the real CPUs will be used.

Comment: Thank you! The scheduler is exactly what I'm looking for. CPU pining is also very interesting.I found these two books useful: _The Definitive Guide to the Xen Hypervisor_ by **David Chisnall** and _The Book of Xen: A Practical Guide for the System Administrator_ by **Chris Takemura**.